# Server requires auth switch, but no auth switch handler provided

Tags: mysql, node.js

I'm using node-mysql2 and receiving this error message when connecting to a production instance of mysql via a wan:

> Server requires auth switch, but no auth switch handler provided

This error is not received when connecting to our local dev server.
Furthmore, connecting to this mysql instance by other means works fine (mysql cli, Toad)

node-mysql2 version: `mysql2@1.1.2` installed via npm.
This error was allegedly fixed back in Aug (RC9) https://github.com/sidorares/node-mysql2/pull/331

I'm not very familiar with mysql, Is there a server setting we can change to workaround this issue?

Comment: Is this question better placed on serverfault?

Comment: if you add `authSwitchHandler: function(data, cb) { console.log(data) }` connection option - what gets printed? The error is a bit strange, if you have no authSwitchHandler in the connection options the client does not set PLUGIN_AUTH capability flag and server should not attempt to send `AuthSwitchRequest` packet

Comment: if you have more data or able to post results with `debug: true` let's move this to node-mysql2 github issue, happy to help

Comment: @AndreySidorov please see https://github.com/sidorares/node-mysql2/issues/504

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So it turns out this error also occurs with other libraries which give more meaningful error messages, e.g.: `Authentication with old password no longer supported, use 4.1 style passwords`
Solution from here: https://forums.mysql.com/read.php?38,593423,593423

```
SET SESSION old_passwords=0;
SET PASSWORD=PASSWORD('YOURDATABASEPASSWORD');
```